# kohana search filter in the same view

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, view, kohana

I am building a virtual store, in kohana, and i want to make a order drop down filter on the product listing.
the order drop down filter should display the products in different orders, as implemented in the controller. My problem: i want the listing of products to be done in one same view, and not to be changed the page as i am choosing a drop down filter (order ascm order desc, etc)

is there any solution for that?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw the filter in a `GET` or `POST` and just check for it in the same controller. You could also look into using a javascript approach but allowing javascript handle the ordering, but with large data sets, that would hurt performance.

Comment: the filter is a drop down list. i mean, i do a ordering action when one selects an option from the drop down. do you advise me to do a js to verify which option is selected from the drop down list? what should i do with get and post in the controller?

Comment: If you do it with PHP, youd probably have a switch or something to determine how you are sorting and then outputting the SQL statement. If you wanna do all the sorting in JS (small data set, under 2000 records) take a look at http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: problem: i have in my view 

     <form name="ordering" id="ordering" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="ordering" value="0">  
    <select id="ordering" name="ordering">   
 <option value=0>Toate produsele</option>
 <option value=1>Pret crescator</option>
 <option value=2>Pret descrescator</option>
 
 
</select>
</form>


and in the controller   $ordering = $_POST['ordering'];       
but i receive an error like: Notice: Undefined index: ordering in  (in the controller). why is that?

Comment: In your index.php change the `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want a really cool AJAX approach:

```
class Ajax_Controller extends Controller {
    public function order() {
        $order = $someModel->order();
        echo json_encode($order);
        die();
    }

}

$.get('ajax/order', {more parameters here}, function(result){
    // use a Jquery table sorter here
})
```